# JPA Many to Many Mapping Update Issue

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've issue on Many to Many mapping when update the record

I've two tables called Pack and Channels and Pack may have many channels and channel can be assigned to many packs. When I create the pack I attach the channel and it works without issue but when I update channels on one pack then all other pack also affect removed assign channels.

After add 2 packs which has ids 3,7 here is many to many table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqthl.png)

Then After update pack id 3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huUCq.png)

Update the one pack then all other packs related channels will be removed

```
Pack Class

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "PacksChannels",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pack_id", referencedColumnName = "packId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id", referencedColumnName = "channelId"),
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"pack_id", "channel_id"})})
List<Channel> channels;
```

Channel Class

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "PacksChannels",
        joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id", referencedColumnName = "channelId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pack_id", referencedColumnName = "packId"),
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"pack_id", "channel_id"})})
@JsonIgnore
List<Pack> packs;
```

Create Pack

```
@Override
public Pack save(Pack pack) {



        Pack savePack = packRepository.save(pack);
        return savePack;
    }
```

Update Pack On Service Layer

```
@Override
    public Pack update(Pack pack, String ref) {

      
            //I've method call find pack by ref and I get the pack according to ref user pass and then update the pack.

            Pack newPack = packRepository.findPackByRef(ref).get();
            newPack.setPackName(pack.getPackName());
            newPack.setChannels(pack.getChannels());
            Pack savedPack = packRepository.save(newPack);

            return savedPack;
        }
```

Way Add Channels

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XYqY.png)

Sample Pack Json Pass to the update pack method

```
{
    "packId": 3,
    "packName": "Test1",
    "ref": "1604905979484.55",
   
    "channels": [
        {
            "channelId": 1,
            "name": "test"
        },
        {
            "channelId": 2,
            "name": "hShenid"
        },
        {
            "channelId": 3,
            "name": "Genesis"
        }
    ]
    
}
```

Comment: So where's the code that performs the create and update? Shall we guess it?

Comment: @Smutje I’ve added that code section

Comment: On updating the pack, do the channels in `pack.getChannels()` contain the references to the other `pack`? Also, where does `pack` come from?

Comment: @Smutje I've added pack json object

Answer (score 0):

After remove the cascade option then problem has been solved

```
@ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "PacksChannels",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pack_id", referencedColumnName = "packId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id", referencedColumnName = "channelId"),
            uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"pack_id", "channel_id"})})
    List<Channel> channels;


@ManyToMany()
@JoinTable(name = "PacksChannels",
        joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id", referencedColumnName = "channelId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pack_id", referencedColumnName = "packId"),
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"pack_id", "channel_id"})})
@JsonIgnore
List<Pack> packs;
```